# grunt assemble error _config.yml file not generated?

Tags: gruntjs, assemble, grunt-assemble

I'm working to try to install the boilerplate-bootstrap example in a effort to learn/play around with assemble. The example fails for me after I try to run grunt saying to please run bower install before continuing. Looking in the Gruntfile.js, I can see that it is looking for vendor/bootstrap/_config.yml. Seems like I'm doing something pretty basic wrong here. the example I'm referring to is listed here:

https://github.com/assemble/boilerplate-bootstrap

Let me know if you have any suggestions at all for me - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the prompt and run `bower install bootstrap`. All will make sense afterwards. The `_config.yml` file is in the root of the Bootstrap project, but you won't find it unless Bootstrap is downloaded with Bower first.

Comment: did this answer the question?